# JMeter data source CSV Data Set Config from command line

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a JMeter setup which reads data from a CSV file configured in CSV Data Set Config element. It works fine, the CSV file is specified in CSV Data Set Config -> Filename.

Now I want to envoke JMeter from command line instead of GUI, and I want to specify a different filename for the above element. How to go about it?

I tried "-JCSVNAME=" but it does not seem to work.

Ideas?

Comment: If you pass a JMeter variable via the command line and use that variable in the CSV filename value it should work.

Comment: Thank you rsp, this helped. I used: "${__property(my_dataset)}" in the CSV Data Set Config "Filename" field, and then -Jmy_dataset=/path/to/file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function in the Filename field of Listener

[image: CSV Filename as property]

Then on command line , add this:

> -Jdatadir=**full path to folder that contains CSV**

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Filename field in CSV Data Set Config to *${__P(datadir)}*.

Include the following option while using jmeter.

> -Jdatadir=path_to_the_config_csv

Example:
`jmeter -Jdatadir=/home/InputData.csv -n -t /home/request.jmx -l some.csv`

[CSV Data Set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Z95.png)